# Need Help joining two queries and avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, join, case, informix

Im trying to trim this query down.  So I am going to somewhat simplify it.  Here is the data I want:

|person.id|badge.bid|person.first_name|person.last_name|person.type|person_user.description|

Every field is unique except for person_user.description. Each record could have up to 40 different person_user.description fields.  Problem is, I am getting duplicates because records have multiple description entries.  Can you help me put those additional duplicates on the same record row like:

|person.id|badge.bid|person.first_name|person.last_name|person.type|1|2|3|4|5|etc..|40|

Here is the query:

```
SELECT person.id, 
       badge.bid, 
       person.first_name, 
       person.last_name, 
       person.type, 
       person_user.description 
FROM   person, 
       badge, 
       person_user 
WHERE  person.id = badge.id 
       AND person.id = person_user.person_id 
       AND badge.bid NOT LIKE "111%" 
       AND badge.access_date >= 20130401 
GROUP  BY person.id, 
          badge.bid, 
          person.first_name, 
          person.last_name, 
          person.type, 
          person_user.description 
ORDER  BY person.id
```

Comment: show your table structure and some data

Comment: edited original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scalar table, populate it using INSERT INTO SELECT and UNION, and then do SELECT DISTINCT from the scalar table.

For example:

```
DECLARE @temptable table (col1 int, col2 int, etc...)

INSERT INTO @temptable

SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE condition=TRUE

UNION

SELECT col1, col2
FROM table2
WHERE condition=TRUE

SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM @temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

If duplicates are your only problem a quick fix would be to just group by id.